# How would I convert a user input (string) to a ConsoleColor?

Tags: vb.net

Obviously, I don't want to use 14 different If statements and two different variables. I'm looking for a shorter and simpler way to have the String converted to its respective ConsoleColor and changing the Foreground Color and then writing to the standard output stream and asking the user if the color change is correct. VB says "Expression Expected." where "Enum" is, despite the fact that this is the only code I have found anywhere on the internet that is even close to what I am looking for. Btw, Sorry, I am quite new to programming.

Any help?

```
Console.WriteLine("WHAT'S YOUR FAVORITE COLOR?")
charlie = Console.ReadLine()

Console.WriteLine("This line is...")
Console.ForegroundColor = CType(Enum.Parse(GetType(ConsoleColor), charlie, true), ConsoleColor)

delta = CStr(charlie)
Console.WriteLine(delta + "? (yes/no)")
Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.Green
foxtrot = Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: have you considered using Enum.Parse?

Comment: I did. That is what is after the first "Console.ForegroundColor = ".

Comment: Oops sorry, speed reading and then I had to shut down a misbehaving browser :-(

Comment: Try putting the keyword Enum in square brackets: `[Enum].Parse (...)`.  My VB is not as strong as it could be, I think it has something to do with [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hwx24eb6(v=vs.140).aspx).  You don't need the CType call since `Enum.Parse` should return an instance of the type described by the first parameter (i.e., `ConsoleColor`).  You will need a try-catch since the string `Charlie` might contain an invalid color name.

Answer (score 2):

Upon further reflection: since you can't trust the input string, it would be better to use `TryParse` rather than `Parse`

```
  Dim temp As ConsoleColor

  If [Enum].TryParse(charlie, True, temp) Then
     Console.ForegroundColor = temp
     Console.WriteLine("This line is...{0}? (yes/no)", charlie)
  Else
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid ConsoleColor name or value", charlie)
  End If
```